# Php remote check what OS the webserver is using

Tags: php, operating-system

Is there a way to check a external websites webserver OS is Linux or Windows in php? I have a web development business and we mainly work on only Linux hosting etc. It would save so much time if I didn't have to find out if a client has a Linux or Windows webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get the information if the web server exposes it.
By default, Apache lets you know a few things including the Server OS. Just have a look at the site's headers.

Comment: Okay, I checked the header array and it has a apach version output. Can this be hidden from me? I only see a example with a Apache (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux) server on the arrays 2nd entry. Will the windows server info be there too, on the 2nd array entry? I guess I could test a couple of websites with this, to try and find a windows server.

Comment: Yes, it can all be hidden from you. I would argue, it should be hidden.
Showing this information could put a server in jeopardy. Whilst the information in itself is not a security problem, if you were to advertised that you are using a version of, say, Apache which has a security hole in it, your users could exploit it.
That's security through obscurity.

Comment: So the best thing would be to check with the user, or say we only deal with linux hosting packages. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will hopefully work

```
$info = get_headers($url); $string0 = implode(' ', $info); $string1 = explode('Server:', $string0);
$pattern = '#^Server:#i'; $matches = preg_grep($pattern, $info);
```

Comment: I need to check the OS before they make online purchase, so that I don't need to refund them if it is a Windows web server.

Comment: This is what it gives me:  /HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 25 Aug 2014 01:35:19 GMT Server: Apache Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6e5014d7b7b87729b904b50d43a25281; path=/ Content-Length: 131326 Content-Type: text/html

Comment: All from a random website

Comment: It seems like this wouldn't work, as if they hide the server info I would be wasting my time. Thanks for the help anyway. I will just have to state that we deal with linux only.